# Why does vscode think the declared package doesn't match the expected package?

Tags: java, macos, maven, visual-studio-code, antlr4

### Situation

I did the following with a project from GitHub

1. cloned the project: git clone https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.git
2. opened the project with: code antlr4
3. opened a file in the project: Antlr4MojoTest.java

The file is found under the following path in the project:
antlr4/antlr4-maven-plugin/src/test/java/org/antlr/mojo/antlr4/Antlr4MojoTest.java

VSCode tells me: *The declared package "org.antlr.mojo.antlr4" does not match the expected package "java.org.antlr.mojo.antlr4"*

### Question

Why does vscode think the expected package is `java.org.antlr.mojo.antlr4`?

Comment: That's the package naming convention, and vscode wants you to open the project from it's root directory, had similar troubles, switched to Intellij since. Does anything look weird in pom.xml ? Try "cd antlr" and "code ."

Comment: The result of the git clone is a directory called `antlr4`.  Do you mean I should open the `antlr4/antlr4-maven-plugin/src/test/java/org/antlr` directory?  Question:  Do you think the 'java' bit in the path could be the problem?

Comment: In short, yes, that is the problem.  AntLR is set up as a Maven project, so you need to use VScode Maven integration (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build) or *manually* configure the source path and classpath for building so that the main/java and test/java trees are separate path entries.

Comment: the Java part is normal, but you have to open the project from it's root, cd antlr4, and open from there ("code .") , you should see a pom.xml file there. if you open it from any other directory, vscode assumes package is wrong since it looks at your CWD. By doing code antlr4, you opened the project from parent directory, so paths are wrong (and path = package)

Comment: This just seems to be a problem with ANTLR4, not VSCode It seems like their antlr4-maven-plugin/pom.xml is set up wrongly. I get the same error when I open this in IntelliJ. Even `mvn install` fails too.

Comment: Specifically, [Line 113](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/antlr4-maven-plugin/pom.xml#L113) should say `src/test/java`, not `src/test`. Either that, or someone has added the `java` folder later by mistake, and `src/test` was actually intentional.

Comment: Anyone want to write their thoughts up as an answer?  I would say going with the standard location would be better than specifying a non-standard location in the pom.  Unless there is a reason for specifying the non-standard location in the pom.  BTW I found a similar question on a SO post from 2 years ago, but no answer about it.

Comment: @Sweeper I did notice that src/test/java is actually the default path.  If I delete line 113 then all is good with the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An Explanation

VSCode expects the class to be in the package `java.org.antlr.mojo` because the plugin pom is set up to include `src/test` as was pointed out by [@Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper).  Here's the line from the module pom:

> ```
> <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
> ```

VSCode correctly understands everything under this to be a package for the included classes.
The remedy is to either change the directory structure to match the pom (eg move the contents of the `java` dir up one level) or change the pom to match the directory structure (eg add '/java' to the end of the testSourceDirectory tag.

IMO changing the pom is the better solution.  Specifically the testSourceDirectory tag should be deleted in its entirety since the default testSourceDirectory already is 'src/test/java' as of version 3.8.6 of the super-pom (org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.8.6:super-pom).  No need to configure something that doesn't need configuring because the default will do (and in this case is correct).